# node express back to back same POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node express API in my application, I am facing below issue for API.

I have API which accept header parameter **test** and values like **1 to 5**. Response is depends on header value, different response for different header parameter value.

Problem : If I am using with Single client (say POSTMAN) it is working fine, but if I am using two POSTMAN with different header parameter say in one window test=2 and 
another window test=5 and if I send both request one after another then on both POSTMAN window I am getting response whichever I am sending first.

For response after some backend work I am sending response.

Below code I am using..

```
router.post('/:sample/:temp', function(req, res){
....
                if(obj.st == "acknowledged"){
                      res.write(message);
                  }else if (obj.st == "completed") {
                          res.write(message);
                          res.end();

                  }
}
```

Update 1 :

After getting request I am waiting for response from MQTT topic where first I am getting **acknowledged** which I am storing like res.write(message) and after some time (may be after 1 second) on same topic I am getting **completed** after that I am sending response to user(API response).

```
router.post('/:sample/:temp', function(req, res){
....
   client.on('message', function(topic, message){
   var obj = JSON.parse(message);
                  if(obj.st == "acknowledged"){
                      res.write(message);
                      res.write("\n\n");
                  }else if (obj.st == "completed") {
                          res.write(message);
                          res.end();
                          client.end();
                  }
              });
}
```

Update 2 :

Using below URL for POST request

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/<path_param1>/<path_param2>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code. With what you've posted it's hard to say.

Comment: @klvs I have updated my question with more code, hope I am able to explain correctly.

Comment: Could you also post the url that you're sending a POST request to?

Comment: @klvs, update the question with URL which I am using to send POST request.